# User permissions on subfolders in a Craft multisite environment

Tags: subdirectory, user-permissions, multisite, craftcms

I have a craft multisite environment with three sites:

- site-one
- site-two
- site-three

and three usergroups to handle permissions for the sites

- users site-one
- users site-two
- users site-three

users in user groups should only be able to access their site assets, for example:
users in group "site-one" can only access the assets of "site-one".

This question https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37249/how-do-you-insert-the-site-name-into-a-default-asset-path helped me to create a structure like this:

uploads/
➝ site-one
➝ site-two
➝ site-three

[asset location with {site.handle}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQlxz.png)

And now the problem:
A user from site-one that is logged in can see all three subfolders of uploads. As far as I understand, there's no possibility to restrict user permissions on subfolders.

What I want to achieve is that users from site-one can only see uploads/site-one and so on.
Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Do all sites have their own "volume"? Once you've created a volume, you can set User Permissions for specific volumes.

Comment: Yes, every site has its own Volume.